# Assigning proper permalink to blog that is part of a website

Tags: permalinks

My blog is a part of a custom website (all done in wordpress). I would like the blog page to be on mywebsite/blog

I've set wordpress so that the root points to a static page and that the posts are displyed under the /blog directory.

I would like the blog post to be in /blog/post-name; but now I see that they are under /post-name

How can I do it?
Thanks.
Andrea

PS: I'm not using wordpress multisite and both the blog and the main website would be run under the same installation of wordpress and as a single website.

Answer (score 1):

Going to assume here that at the moment your blog posts show up as http://domain/post-name and you would like them to show up as http://domain/blog/post-name

If that's the case, all you have to do is go to Settings>Permalinks and in the Custom Structure field put: /blog/%postname%/